# Adjust the angle of the objects in the group in Unity,the object also grow longer

Tags: unity-game-engine

Excuse me, may I adjust the angle of the objects in the group in Unity, why does the object also grow longer?

If the group X Y Z scale=1, there will be no such problem. But here is the need to control the overall scaling through the program.

[image]

Object hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Could you also post the hierarchy and how these objects are rotated/scaled? Also this object's Z-Axis Scale is set to 0. That seems wrong to me.

Comment: Hello, the second picture should have a group structure. If the group X Y Z scale=1, there will be no such problem. But here is the need to control the overall scaling through the program.

Comment: @pixlhero what's wrong with a _zero scale_ for one of the axis?  You can use it to turn a cube into a square.  It might not be particularly efficient but it works.

Comment: Consider using a Unity **Parent Constraint**.  That way you can apply transforms to objects in your hierarchy at runtime without it affecting the others.   I use this to ensure that my fighter jet's wheel's and shock absorbers _bob up and down_ **but** that when the plane moves _the wheels and shocks go with it_.   https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2021/10/17/flight-sim-project-update/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the rotation is applied to an object that is inside another object that has **uneven** scaling applied.

This is actually what you would expect. If you have for example an [equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle) and scale one axis by 2, the angles will not be 60 degrees anymore.

It's a bit hard to figure out what the goal of OP is, but either scaling the `Desktops` object **evenly** or having the rotation on the `Desktops` object itself. Maybe a different setup is required altogether.

Comment: What's wrong with a _zero scale_ for one of the axis?  You can use it to turn a cube into a square.  It might not be particularly efficient but it works.

Comment: It messes with stuff like colliders. But it's true it has its uses, I'll remove it for this answer.

Comment: You shouldn't have colliders and visuals in the same tree branch.  For any game object, you should create child "Visuals" and "Colliders" nodes and place the actual colliders and visuals into the appropriate node.  Then each can have their own transforms without it affecting the other.   Then if I want that cube flattened into a nice square I can. ;)

Comment: true, then lets say zero scale is fine if the object is purely visual.